# Que signifie « je te craquerai » en français ?

Tags: expressions

On s'est dit au revoir et un ami a dit l'expression suivante :

> « ... Quand tu reviens je te craquerai... ».

Quelle est la signification ?
Quelles sont les interprétations ?

Comment: à ma connaissance, ca ne se dit pas.

Comment: Peut-être avez vous mal compris, même au niveau de l'argot parisien ça ne se dit pas. De quelle région était cette personne ?

Comment: Je ne connais pas l'expression... Mais, quelques pistes possibles : Êtes-vous intime avec cette personne ? « Croquer » plus que « craquer ». Avez-vous été secret/distant ? « craquer » pour découvrir des secrets/passer une défense ? Est-ce par écrit informatique ? Possible auto-correction, mais là, ça sera plus dur de deviner...

Comment: Peut-être dans le sens de [_raconter des histoires_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/craquer/1), causer ? Un verbe comme [_jaser_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jaser) a aussi cette analogie avec l'oiseau.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bonjour, il existe plusieurs possibilités en fonction du contexte et de votre région. Étant du Québec, je te donne les références de là, mais si tu es Français, ça peut être différent, et peut même différer que tu sois de la métropole ou de la campagne.

Craquer quelqu'un peut vouloir dire le déchiffrer (comme cracker un code), apprendre ses secrets. Dans ton contexte, si tu as été mystérieux ou a tenté de lui cacher certains trucs, cela pourrait se résumer à "Je saurai la vérité prochaine fois". Cela peut-être vu de manière positive comme négative.

Craquer pour quelqu'un veut dire tomber en amour avec cette personne, où tout simplement avoir des sentiments singulier pour elle. Dans ton contexte, il manquerait le mot *pour*. Alors à moins que tu ai mal entendu ou qu'il ait mal phrasé, cela ne risque pas d'en être le sens. Toutefois, si vous êtes amants, ou relativement proche pour qu'il y aille une chance que, ça pourrait tout aussi bien être cela.

**Au Québec seulement** *(cette définition peut ne pas convenir ailleurs)*: Craquer quelqu'un veut dire le blesser, lui faire mal, le briser, mais pas de manière physique, plutôt de manière figurée comme de l'intimidation.

Et une phrase comme,

> À ton retour, je vais te craquer (ou je te craquerai)

est vraisemblablement une menace à ce niveau, mais dépendamment de votre relation, cela peut tout aussi être amical. Si vous aviez joué à une partie d'Échec et que tu as gagnés, cela sera plus du genre "J'aurai ma vengeance, je vais te vaincre, mon ami".

.

En espérant t'avoir aidé, penses à donner plus de contexte comme ta région et ta relation avec l'autre si jamais.